# How to pass array as annotation argument?

Tags: java, arrays, annotations, argument-passing

I have following class.

```
public class MultipartFileWrapper {
    @Extensions({".jpg",".png",".gif",".bmp",".mp4"})
    MultipartFile multipartFile;  
    ...
}
```

Now I want to extract format to constants.
But I don't understand how to replace

```
@Extensions({".jpg",".png",".gif",".bmp",".mp4"})
```

If I have array

```
String[] validFormats
```

which contains listed formats. I want to write something like this:

```
public class MultipartFileWrapper {
        @Extensions(validFormats)
        MultipartFile multipartFile;  
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I don't think annotations accept arrays as part of the arguments because the values may change during runtime?

Comment: Hmm...How can I extract configuration at this case?

Answer (score 0):

Now i understood your problem... may be  you try this method in your class:

```
public String[] getExtensions()throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException{
    return MultipartFileWrapper.class.getDeclaredField("multipartFile").getAnnotation(Extensions.class).value();
}
```

Call the method and geting the "annoted" values